# Hard to explain, mimic this link bar hover effect

Tags: html, css, hover

So if you hover between "home" and "products" you'll see the bottom border appear and it appears to be follow the cursor. Can anyone think of how I can apply that to the entire link bar so the border basically follows the mouse when hovering over these links?

```css
#linkbar {
  width: 54%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.linklist {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.linklist li {
  font: normal 1.6em 'Nanum Myeongjo', serif;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
}

.linklist a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  transition: border .3s, color .2s;
}

.linklist li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

.linklist a:hover {
  color: maroon;
  display: block;
}

.linklist a:after {
  content: '';
  width: 0px;
  height: 1px;
  display: block;
  background: maroon;
  transition: .3s;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.linklist a:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}

.home:after {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="linkbar">
  <ul class="linklist">
    <li><a class="home" href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!--linkbar-->
```

Let me know if you need anything else. I appreciate whatever help you guys can offer. I'm still learning the principles of CSS and I'm just now scratching on the surface of selectors

Comment: It's not following your cursor, it's just animation for first element starts from right and for all other elements from left

Comment: These links should be able to help you: [Codepen example](https://codepen.io/rm/pen/ldhon), [webdesign tutplus](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-build-a-shifting-underline-hover-effect-with-css-and-javascript--cms-28510), [CSS-tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/jquery-magicline-navigation/). I prefer the tutplus one, because it doesn't move the line again when hover is lost.

Comment: @Justinas that's why I said it appeared as if the border were following the cursor. I enjoyed all of those articles Chris, I now know it's called the sliding underline!

Comment: Great to hear! Please upvote if I was any help. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have edited code. I think This Will Help You.

```css
#linkbar {
  width: 54%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.linklist {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.linklist li {
  font: normal 1.6em 'Nanum Myeongjo', serif;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
}

.linklist a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background:transparent;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  transition: border .3s, color .2s;
}

.linklist li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

.linklist a:hover {
  color: maroon;
  display: block;
}

.linklist a:after {
  content: '';
  width: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  background: #aaa;
  z-index:-1;
  transition: .3s;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.linklist a:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}

.home:after {
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="linkbar">
  <ul class="linklist">
    <li><a class="home" href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!--linkbar-->
```

Comment: That only really added a background color to it, thank you for your assistance, though